# Eloquent whereIn not working with relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying the following query to **get all questions for certain categories**.

```
$categories = Category::with('question')->whereIn('id', [2,3])->get();
```

My relations are defined as following

```
class Category extends Model {

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Question extends Model {

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

**The result** is a null for questions

```
{id: 2, name: "Communicatie", question: null}
```

Comment: Really `Category` belongsTo `Question`? I suppose each question belongs to one category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't make your life hard. You are trying to get `questions` but you are calling

```
$categories = ...
```

---

Really, if you want questions, then start with questions and it will be easier to find solution:

```
$questions = Question:: .... ->get();
```

Now, just find read [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations) and here we go:

```
$questions = Question::whereHas('catgory', function ($q) use ($catsIds) {
    $q->whereIn('categories.id', $catsIds);
})->get();
```

And btw your way is getting what you asked for as well, only it's cumbersome to get it:

```
$categories = Category::with('question')->whereIn('id', [2,3])->get();

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
   $category->questions; // collection of questions you wanted
}

// you could now merge the questions of all the categories, but it's not the way
```

Comment: You're welcome. Eloquent provides sooo many handy features, that you really should always think of what you want to achieve, then look for something to get you there, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your `question` model be in `hasMany` relation instead of `belongsTo` ? You basically used `belongsTo` in both directions which is definitely not correct. Is it many-to-many relationship or what ?

EDIT: I meant your `Question` model should be `belongsTo` and `Category` should be `hasMany` :)

```
class Category extends Model {

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
    }
}


class Question extends Model {

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result. I'll update the question with the correct relation

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`category_id` in (2, 3))

Comment: Thank you! it's solved, thanks for pointing out the relation errors

Comment: Check my updated answer. This is how your relation should work. This way you should have ```categories``` table and ```questions``` table and in ```questions``` one you should have ```category_id``` column. Then it should work.